subgroup of Spin(8) with Hermitian generators
It is known that the Lie algebra elements of $Spin(8)$ can be written in the form (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.13690 Eq.(2.5))
$$
X = A^{ij}(a_i a^{\dagger}_j-a^{\dagger}_i a_j) + \beta^{ij}a^{\dagger}_i a^{\dagger}_j + B^{ij}a_i a_j
$$
where the indexes run from 1 to 4 and $a_i$ and $a^{\dagger}_i$ form a Witt basis of null vectors in $C\ell(8)$.
Now, if I consider the special case $X^{\dagger}=X$, my Lie algebra elements will be hermitian and equal to
$$
X = A^{ij}(a_i a^{\dagger}_j-a^{\dagger}_i a_j) + B^{ij}(a^{\dagger}_i a^{\dagger}_j + a_i a_j)
$$
so the resulting subgroup should be related to some $SU(N)$.
My question is, what subgroup is this?
